# glfw not updating window on my computer only

Tags: opengl, glfw

I have written a small application that uses opengl for graphics and glfw for window handling. However, when I draw something different on the screen, the window is not updated unless I unfocus it and go back by alt tab for example or resize it. However, I tested the exact same program on a different computer and it worked perfectly, so it must be a problem with my computer or a bug with glfw, how can I fix/debug this?

Here is the code I used when debugging, nothing changes unless I alt tab:

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

// Shaders
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Assignment1", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions, this is for input from the keyboard
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


    // Build and compile our shader program
    // Vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Link shaders
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Left  
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Right 
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f  // Top   
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)

    // Game loop
    int mo = 0;
    auto mode = GL_LINE;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
        glfwPollEvents();

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glfwSwapInterval(3);
        if (mo++ % 2)
        {
            glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
            mode = GL_LINE;
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        }
        else
        {
            glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
            mode = GL_FILL;
        }

        // Render
        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw our first triangle
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, mode);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Swap the screen buffers
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

The above code was used to test as many things as possible this may be easier to check, when pressing l or f nothing happens, but again alt tab or resizing will display the result:

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

// Shaders
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

    auto type = GL_LINE;
int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Assignment1", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions, this is for input from the keyboard
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


    // Build and compile our shader program
    // Vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Link shaders
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Left  
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Right 
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f  // Top   
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)

    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        std::cout << type << "\n";

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
            glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw our first triangle
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, type);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Swap the screen buffers
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    else    if (key == GLFW_KEY_F)
    {
        type = GL_FILL;
    }
    else if (key == GLFW_KEY_L)
    {
        type = GL_LINE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me turn that around on you: "I tested GLFW on a different computer, so it must be a bug in your program."  You see how that logic really doesn't work?  Testing your program on one computer doesn't mean it's correct.  It's probably a bug in your program, but it could be a bug in GLFW.  You are calling `glfwSwapBuffers()`, right?

Comment: yes, also I am heavily following the online tutorials at learnopengl.com, but whenever I try to draw a different shape by changing value of variable through keyboard new shape is not drawn

Comment: @fYre: And how could we *possibly* know how or why that's happening without seeing your code? The more certain you are that a bug isn't in a location, the more likely it is to be hiding there.

Comment: Why are you calling `glfwMakeContextCurrent` in your loop? You only need to call that once (after you get the window) unless you're rendering to multiple windows. Also you should not need to call `glfwSwapInterval` in a loop either.

Comment: when debugging I was trying everything possible...I pretty much tried everything I could think off, including swap intervals in different locations and different values